# Android 65K method limit

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I was working on a project for past 1 year. Now there is a need for GCM push notifications. The project itself is very big and I ran into 65K error when I have added google play services library. There seems to be no work around with Eclipse IDE so I have ported my eclipse project to Android Studio. But I'm getting the following error.

:MyApp:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':MyApp:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents'.

> Java heap space
>   es file.
>   For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
>   *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
>   [Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
> [Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: A multidex configuration

Comment: Added compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' and multiDexEnabled true under defaultConfig

Comment: If you running into the "no method may exceed 64K" thing, is there any way you can split the offending class up into seperate classes?

Comment: I have removed unused packages from the google play service library and have added multidex support library to my existing project. But still I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using proguard to clear unused methods. it worked for me after i ran into the 65k methods limit problem.